# ExtJS 6 - Store $binding is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to perform certain operations when a store is loaded. The problem is when the 'load' event of the store is triggered, '$binding' is undefined, and thus the 'owner' property is unavailable.

The store and its listener for the 'load' event are defined in the ViewModel:

```
    Ext.define('App.view.TSegmentacionFrmViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.TSegmentacionFrm',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Store',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    stores: {
        oStoreSegmentacion: {
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'App.model.oGrid',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                extraParams: {
                    cmd: 'Get',
                    cCodClass: 'SegmentacionBrw'
                },
                url: "TGlobalData.ashx",
                useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'aResultado',
                    totalProperty: 'nRows'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                load: 'onJsonstoreLoad'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The store binding is defined in the View (line 58 of the following code):

```
    Ext.define('App.view.TSegmentacionFrm', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.TSegmentacionFrm',

    requires: [
        'App.view.TSegmentacionFrmViewModel',
        'App.view.TSegmentacionFrmViewController',
        'Ext.tab.Tab',
        'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
        'Ext.toolbar.Separator',
        'Ext.grid.Panel',
        'Ext.view.Table',
        'Ext.grid.column.Action',
        'Ext.form.Label',
        'Ext.grid.column.RowNumberer'
    ],

    config: {
        [...]
    },

    controller: 'TSegmentacionFrm',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'TSegmentacionFrm'
    },
    cls: 'CustomTabs',
    itemId: 'TSegmentacionFrm',
    activeTab: 0,
    deferredRender: false,

    initConfig: function(instanceConfig) {
        var me = this,
            config = {
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        itemId: 'oPnlHist',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'vbox',
                            align: 'stretch'
                        },
                        bind: {
                            title: '{lbl_ListadoHist}'
                        },
                        dockedItems: [
                            {
                                [...]
                            }
                        ],
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'TMainBrowseGrid',
                                cBrwName: 'oBrwSegmentacion',
                                cCodForm: 'SegmentacionFrm',
                                cls: 'CustomGrid',
                                flex: 1,
                                itemId: 'oGridHistorico',
                                bind: {
                                    store: '{oStoreSegmentacion}'
                                },
                                listeners: {
                                    selectionchange: 'onOGridProductosSelectionChange'
                                },
                                columns:
                                    [...]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            };
        [...]
    },
});
```

And this is the onJsonstoreLoad method, in the ViewController:

```
    Ext.define('App.view.TSegmentacionFrmViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.TSegmentacionFrm',

    onJsonstoreLoad: function (store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {


        // This '$binding' is undefined
        // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined at g.onJsonstoreLoad
        var oView = store.$binding.owner.getView();

        [...]

    }

});
```

What am I doing wrong? The person who wrote this some time ago says it worked, but now it seems to be broken. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$binding` is some internal property, it's not part of the API, don't use it. By virtue of the callback being in the controller, just call `this.getView()`.